# LinkedIn API - how to query for the total number of connections?

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I am trying to query for the total number of connections like this:

```
/people/id=QM86-RIKjb:(connections total)
```

and using the API example here: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api

in the xml example towards the bottom the show this field: `<connections total="" >`

I am trying to query for it, but I get an exception that I have a bad URI:

```
URI::InvalidURIError: bad URI(is not URI?): /v1/people/id=QM86-RIKjb:(connections total)
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Is there a correct way to query for such parameters?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the connection count from the [Profile API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api), you can ask the API directly:

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=nbqwYraDfd:(num-connections,num-connections-capped)`

Which will return (depending on the connection count):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
  <num-connections>500</num-connections>
  <num-connections-capped>true</num-connections-capped>
</person>
```

Keep in mind that there are restrictions on the fields available to the viewing user - check the [Profile Fields](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields) document for details. For instance, it is not possible to get 'connections of connections' - if, in your example above, `nbqwYraDfd` represents the current viewing user, you can use:

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=nbqwYraDfd:(connections)`

Which will return:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
  <connections total="XXX" count="YYY" start="0">
    <person>
    ...
    </person>
  </connections>
</person>
```

And then check the value of total by traversing the XML (language dependant).

However, if `nbqwYraDfd` is a connection of the current user, or a non-connection, you will get a 403 response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
  <status>403</status>
  <timestamp>1337954306491</timestamp>
  <request-id>25P44ZN249</request-id>
  <error-code>0</error-code>
  <message>Access to other member's connections denied</message>
</error>
```

Comment: However, `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=nbqwYraDfd:(network:(networkStats))` might be more efficient than :(connections), and better than :(num-connections) when # connection is >500

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do this ( you cannot get an attribute of a particular tag)

Do this,

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=nbqwYraDfd:(connections)
```

Get the response returned and parse the XML returned in your programming language and read the attribute `total` of `connections` tag.

If you are interested in getting total count only, I would suggest this query to filter the response returned,

```
http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=nbqwYraDfd:(connections:())
```

Which programming language are you using, may be I can help in parsing the XML returned.

Comment: @Joshwant thanks, I am using Ruby. I get the LoadError: no such file to load when trying to do this url which ends like this: "/people/id=QM86-RIKjb:(connections:())"

Comment: Are you sure `QM86-RIKjb` is a valid id and you have access to it ?

Comment: Does this work ?

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=QM86-RIKjb:(connections:(id))` ?

Comment: @Joshwant that other answer people/id=nbqwYraDfd:(num-connections) worked.   But yours was helpful too. Thank you!

Comment: :) My answer works too , you just need to figure out the problem in your code :)

Comment: This answer works better when # connections >500, then num-connection is always be 500, while connections._total is the exact number, say 1034.

Comment: However, `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=nbqwYraDfd:(network:(networkStats))` might be more efficient.