# LinkedIn API - how to get the number of a users connections if it is over 500?

Tags: rest, linkedin-api

I was able to [get this url to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745255/linkedin-api-how-to-query-for-the-total-number-of-connections) with their api: /people/id=123:(num-connections-total)

It returns the number of connections, but if the number of connections is over 500, it just returns 500.  Is there a way to get it to return the actual exact number?

I am working from this docs page:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-api

Also this page has a lot more on the possible fields:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/profile-fields#profile

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are retrieving connections for the viewing user, then yes, you would use the value in the `total` attribute from the collection returned from a call to:

`http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/id=123:(connections)`

Where 123 is the viewing member's id. The return values look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<person>
  <connections total="XXX" count="YYY" start="0">
    <person>
    ...
    </person>
  </connections>
</person>
```

If you are trying to pull the connection count for the viewing user's connections, or other un-connected users, then no, there is no way, [as connections of connections are not available via the APIs](https://developer.linkedin.com/comment/14498#comment-14498). You can see this behavior on LinkedIn.com as well, where members with more than 500 are just shown as having 500+ connections.

Comment: thanks, but I don't need the viewing user.  I am trying to get it for the user's friends who commented.  LinkedIn gives ids of people who comment on a status update, so i am trying to see how many connections each person who comments on my status update has.

Comment: Also, I am not trying to get the connections of my friends. I am just trying to get the number of the connections they each have.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately only up to 500 (same behavior as on LinkedIn.com)

Comment: thanks, I accepted the answer, but just if you found it... is there anywhere that it says that concretely?

Comment: The comment I linked to in the answer is a post from a LinkedIn employee. Additionally, the [Connections API docs](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/connections-api) state "...You cannot get connections of that user's connections..." in bullet point #3

Comment: yeah, but you see, they make a distinction between connections (which is a full object with lots of data) and num_connections which is just the total number of connections. I think in the posts you found, they were talking about the former, and i am trying to figure out the ladder.

Comment: Unless you iterate through the full `connections` collection, which you can't get for anyone but the current user, there is no way to get the total number of connections if that total exceeds 500. This is the reason for the `num-connections-capped` field.