# LinkedIn API - How to query for the total number of connections if it is over 500?

Tags: linkedin-api

I can not get the total number of connections from a user when they exceed 500 connections.

The call I make is the following for a specific user:
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(num-connections)?oauth2_access_token={0}

But the answer only brings 500 connections, when it actually has 3,819 Followers:

```
<? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone = "yes"?>
<person>
   <num-connections> 500 </ num-connections>
</ person>
```

Is there any way to get the 3,819 Followers?
Should the user do something in his LinkedIn profile to make this value readable by the API?

Thanks in advance.

Manuel M.N.

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting the capped limit. Look at [LinkedIn API - how to query for the total number of connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745255/linkedin-api-how-to-query-for-the-total-number-of-connections)

Try instead a call to V2:

'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&count=0'

```
"{"elements":[],"paging":{"total":1234,"count":0,"start":0}}"
```

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/connections-api#find-total-number-of-connections

Comment: Hi s1mpl3, the call is the following:
'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?oauth2_access_token=XXXXX&q=viewer&count=0'
And the response is:
The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
Any idea?
Thanks in Advance.