# Oauth2 linkedin- access to the total connection number of a user via accessToken

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api

I am trying to get the number of connections of a user who is signed via Oauth2 when I get access to the accessToken.

I tried to do something like this but it failed:

```
fetch('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/connections?q=viewer&count=0', {   method: 'GET',   headers: {     'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,     'Accept': 'application/json',     'Content-Type': 'application/json'   } }) .then(response => {   if (!response.ok) {     throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);   }   return response.json(); })
```

I basically receive a permission error:
`{   "serviceErrorCode": 100,   "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-viewer /connections",   "status": 403 }`
From my understanding it is not possible to get the number of connection of a user when you have access to the accessToken via Oauth2. But when I see the permission error then it came to my mind that may be it is possible but I am doing it in a wrong way.

There is another post located at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10745255/linkedin-api-how-to-query-for-the-total-number-of-connections` that looks to retry the number of the connections from id. I also tried to get the id of the user who I have accessToken of him via

```
fetch('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me', {   method: 'GET',   headers: {     'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,     'Accept': 'application/json',     'Content-Type': 'application/json'   } }) .then(response => {   if (!response.ok) {     throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);   }   return response.json(); })
```

but it returns:
`{   "serviceErrorCode": 0,   "message": "Resource null does not exist",   "status": 404 }`

Thanks